# How to change the line properties of a plot in switch environment within a for-loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, properties, plot, switch-statement

I have data from simulations in one single .dat file. Depending on certain criteria ('bu') that is contained in one column of the file (#13 here), I want to plot the data with different markers, while also defining the markersize and markerface properties.
What I have is a switch environment for the different cases - defining which markers and properties I want, and all this in a for-loop, to go through all simulation data.

I've tried the following:

```
for i=1:s1(1)

bu = data1(i,13);

switch bu

    case 1
        set(h,'kd','MarkerSize',14,'MarkerFaceColor','k');
    case 2
        set(h,'kd','MarkerSize',14);
    case 3
        set(h,'k>','MarkerSize',14,'MarkerFaceColor','k');
    case 4
        set(h,'ks','MarkerSize',14,'MarkerFaceColor','k');
    case 5
        set(h,'ks','MarkerSize',14);
    case 6
        set(h,'ko','markersize',14);
    case 7
        set(findobj(gca,'k^','MarkerSize',14,'MarkerFaceColor','k'));    
end

figure(1);
h=plot(Re1(i),A1(i)); hold on
end
```

First I tried to use a handle 'h', but it said it was undefined, I guess since the h=plot comes later. Then I tried findobj in the last case (which is the case for the first simulation, so this gives the error in the first round), didn't work either ("Incomplete property-value pair" - not sure what it means here).

I also tried putting all these properties in a string like

```
str=['kd','MarkerSize',14,'MarkerFaceColor','k']
```

then plot with

```
h=plot(Re1(i),A1(i),str); hold on
```

but it doesn't work with/without brackets either.

Now I don't have any further ideas, thankful for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest change for you is to put the plot options in a cell array in the switch block. For example:

```
options = {'kd', 'MarkerSize', 14, 'MarkerFaceColor', 'k'};
```

Later, when you plot:

```
plot(x, y, options{:})
```

Another way I've done it is to set variables and use them in the plot command:

```
style = 'kd';
markerSize = 14;
markerFaceColor = 'k';
plot(x, y, style, 'MarkerSize', markerSize, 'MarkerFaceColor', markerFaceColor);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few different ways to do that, one of them - create all plot objects before hand and then fill them with both data and formatting:

```
figureHandle = figure;
for i=1:s1(1)
plotHandle(i) = plot(0,0); %just creating valid handle for future here
end;
```

- code above before your for loop with bu switch, and then in your switch

set(ph(i),'kd','MarkerSize',14,'MarkerFaceColor','k', 'Xdata', Re(1), 'Ydata', A1(i));

Approach with str would work too, except you would need two cell arrays - option nad value like that:

```
firstoption = 'kd';
option = {'MarkerSize','MarkerFaceColor'};
value = {14,'k'};

h=plot(Re1(i),A1(i),firstoption); 
for i=1:length(option)
set(h,option{i},value{i});
end;
```